# Moving a view and changing the image of uiimageview is not performing the move of the view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiimageview

I have a very simple situation: in a view i have an UIImageView and one UILabel. at a moment in time I want to change the position of the label and in the same method to change the image of the uiimageview.

```
self.myLabel.center = CGPointMake(158, 230);
self.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anotherImage.png"];
```

But this code will change only the image and will not move the label. If i comment out the second line and run the code then the label will change the position.

Dose anybody have an idea why is not working? Or a valid workaround for this problem?

Comment: That's just odd. Are you *sure* 100% that's happening? There's no reason it should!

Comment: yes I am sure, I have did the test multiple times

Comment: Can you show us the whole method then please?

Comment: that are the only two lines on my method: (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField

Comment: Oh, right. Are you also returning YES/NO? You need to.

Comment: I am returning YES. The thing is i want to move some views when the keyboard is displayed.

Comment: Have you tried setting the image before the center? Setting the image to a UIImage variable to see if its not nil? Creating a test project with a textfield label and uiimageview and doing the same thing?

Comment: @alinoz There's something else going on, because the above code is fine. Admittedly, changing that sort of stuff in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` rather than `textFieldDidBeginEditing` is strange, but it shouldn't affect it. I just tested the above code and it works fine. When the keyboard pops up, label moves and image changes fine. It's got to be something simple, but it isn't the above code. By the way, I assume you have the "Use Autolayout" box unchecked?

Comment: @yuf: Yes, I have tried that too. the image is not nil since the image is updated just the label is not changing the position.

Comment: @Rob: I had the auto layout enabled. I disabled that and everything is fine. Please put your comment as an answer in order to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested the above code and it works fine. When the keyboard pops up, label moves and image changes fine. The issue in your program has to be something simple, but it isn't the above code.

Now that we've got iOS6, whenever I see posts about changes to `frame` coordinates not seeming to behave properly when done via code, I immediately suspect the Autolayout settings:

[image]

Make sure you uncheck that, because otherwise constraint based logic will override any attempts to manually adjust settings via code. (Or, if you want to use Autolayout, rather than setting frame coordinates, programmatically adjust your constraints to achieve the desired result.)

Anyway, it sounds like that was you issue. Glad you solved it!

Comment: yep, this was solving the problem, the strange part is: when i was not changing the image of the uiimageview the change of coordinates for my label was working fine. thank you Rob.

Comment: Yeah, I'm surprised by that, but perhaps the setting of the image is retriggering the "apply constraints" logic. I'm not entirely sure. But at least we know the root problem.